# Cosmos DB Sql how to get distinct list of items in array?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Say you have the following documents stored in cosmos db and want to get the distinct list of Keywords for all document in Partition p1.

```
[
    {
        "PartitionKey": "p1",
        "id": "i1",
        "Property1": "somevalue",
        "Keywords": [
            "k1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "PartitionKey": "p1",
        "id": "i2",
        "Property1": "some other value",
        "Keywords": [
            "k1",
            "k2"
        ]
    }
]
```

In this case I would want to get a list with `k1, k2` returned. I know you can do distinct on individual properties, but how to do it for values in an array like this? Is that possible?

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use distinct to get array result,you could do the trick to implement your requirements with Cosmos DB [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs),i think. Please see my example js code:

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT r.Keywords FROM root r where r.PartitionKey = "p1"',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var map = {};
             for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
                 var keyArray = feed[i].Keywords;
                 for(var j=0;j<keyArray.length;j++){
                        map[keyArray[j]] = keyArray[j]
                 }
                 var returnArray = [];
                 for(var key in map){
                    returnArray.push(map[key]);
                }
             }
            response.setBody(returnArray);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I want to use distinct, but not sure how to get a list of distinct items across all the arrays using a query.

Comment: Yes,i know your origin requirements, but i think distinct can't across all the arrays. The stored procedure is a workaround.